# how to pass string to function in tcl?

Tags: tcl, proc

I have a function like this:

```
proc test { {isSet "false"} } {
   if {isSet  == "true"} {
    # do something
   }
}
```

but when I call this proc, how to pass `false` or `true`:

```
test "false" or test false?
```

Comment: Either is fine, but test "false" is more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong (ignoring the fact you're using bare word `isSet` in your `if` conditional expression which won't work). Instead do

```
proc test {{isSet "false"}} {
   if {$isSet} {
       # do something
   }
}
```

This will allow you to call your `test` proc however you wish:

```
test 0
test 1
test [expr {1 == 0}]
test yes
test false
test "no"
test {true}
test "off"
```

etc…

The underlying idea is that the Tcl interpreter will try to *interpret* the value contained in the `isSet` variable as a value of a boolean type; there's a set of rules for it to do that:

- A value 0 of integer type is false.
- A value different from 0 of integer type is true.
- Everything else is first converted to a string and then

  - A string literally equal to one of `yes`, `true` or `on` is true;
  - A string literally equal to one of `no`, `false` or `off` is false.

The rules applied for interpreting a string as a boolean are described in the [`Tcl_GetBoolean()` manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/GetInt.htm).

And you're making another mistake in your assumptions: Tcl does not have explicit string and boolean types (as it's typeless) so `"false"` and `false` are exactly the same things to the Tcl interpreter at the time it parses your script as double quotes and curly braces are used in Tcl *for grouping,* not for specifying types of literals (and Tcl does not have literals).  So I would recommend to start from [the tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) to get better grip on these ideas.

The types I mentioned when I described interpreting of values as boolean are internal to Tcl values and are not user-visible — yes, internally Tcl caches "native" representation of values so when you do `set x [expr {1 + 2}]`, internally the value assigned to `x` will have an integer type but this is really an implementation detail.

Comment: +1 The other possibility is to use `string is boolean`, `string is true` and `string is false` in some combination. I'd note that they're only really useful when parsing user values (where “`you betcha!`” is a distinct possibility for input), as opposed to values that come from a program.